# Validate if an object is not in array of object and throw in js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I have an object to validate if any from an array of object is not the same

```
const obj = {
    question: "What is your dog name?",
  answer: "Browny"
}

const array = [
  {
    question: "What is your name?",
    answer: "Diana"
  },
  {
    question: "What is your dog name?",
    answer: "Browny"
  }
]
```

I tried filtering and comparing them but it only check the first obj

```
array.filter(arr => {
  if (arr.question !== obj.question) response.status(409).json({message: 'Wrong question chosen'}) 
  if (arr.answer !== obj.answer) response.status(409).json({message: 'Please type the right answer'})

  else response.status(200)
})
```

I check on this [JS: Filter array of objects by array, when object key is an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62291977/js-filter-array-of-objects-by-array-when-object-key-is-an-array-of-objects) but it got me kinda confusing

I hope you guys can help me, thanks in advance!

Comment: Object comparison is based on object identity. Two different objects, even if they contain the same property names and property values, are never `===` to each other.

Comment: `filter` should return an array of the same type as the array it was called on. Any other behavior would be unexpected and would likely lead to bugs. It seems like you don't want to filter so much as check if any of the elements in the array are the same as your example.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript -- find matching object in array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36049542/javascript-find-matching-object-in-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ciao, you can follow this example:

```js
const obj = {
    question: "What is your dog name?",
  answer: "Browny"
};

const array = [
  {
    question: "What is your name?",
    answer: "Diana"
  },
  {
    question: "What is your dog name?",
    answer: "Browny"
  }
];

let correct_answer = array.filter(el => el.question === obj.question)[0];


if (correct_answer.answer === obj.answer) console.log("correct answer");
else console.log("wrong answer");
```

So your code becomes:

```
let correct_answer = array.filter(arr => arr.question === obj.question);

if (correct_answer.length === 0) response.status(409).json({message: 'Wrong question chosen'}) 
else {
   if (correct_answer[0].answer === obj.answer) response.status(200);
   else response.status(409).json({message: 'Please type the right answer'});
}
```